# Combine Multiple MsgBox into one

Tags: excel, vba

When we open this workbook, this code will look through a range and find cells that contain the text "RCA Pending" and will popup a MsgBox letting the user know which row in that column contains the specific text. The problem is, if there are multiple rows containing this text, there will also be multiple MsgBox popups.

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

Dim i As Variant
Dim FindRange As Range
Set FindRange = Range("AB2:AB2000")

    For Each i In FindRange
        If i = "RCA Pending" Then

        MsgBox "Found 'RCA Pending' in cell" & " " & i.Address, vbExclamation, "Attention"

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

What needs to be changed in this code so that there is only one popup that lists all the rows where "RCA Pending" was found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()    

Dim i As Variant
Dim FindRange As Range
Dim Msg As String
Set FindRange = Range("AB2:AB2000")

    For Each i In FindRange
       If i = "RCA Pending" Then

        If Msg = "" Then
         Msg = "Found 'RCA Pending' in cell" & " " & i.Address
        Else
         Msg = Msg & Chr(10) & "Found 'RCA Pending' in cell" & " " & i.Address
        End If

       End If
    Next i
    If Msg <> "" Then MsgBox Msg, vbExclamation, "Attention"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `Chr(13)` ? Shouldn't that be `Chr(10)` ? [edit] My apologies. Apparently a solo `Chr(13)` interprets as a next-line character as well.

Comment: @Jeeped, is there any problem with using `Chr(13)`, I use `Chr(13)` in VBA and `Chr(10)` in excel cells.

Comment: No, it appears to interpret as a next-line character although strictly speaking, I do not believe it should. A carriage return (e.g. `Chr(13)` ) should always be accompanied by a linefeed (e.g. `Chr(10)` ) but a `Chr(10)` can stand by itself. It **should** be `vbCrLf`  or `vbLf`, not `vbCr`.

Comment: @Fadi Thanks, this worked perfectly. And as I finished testing and showed it to my colleague, the requirement changed...lol. Now they just want a count of how many times "RCA Pending" appears in the range, and do not need the address of each one. But your answer is great reference for future needs.

Comment: @IronMan, You are Welcome. and to count you can use `MsgBox WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("AB"), "RCA Pending")`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
Sub Msgbox_It()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim i As Range
    Dim FindRange As Range
    Dim Msg As String

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")    'name of worksheet
    With sh
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AB").End(xlUp).Row
        Set FindRange = .Range("AB2:AB" & LstRw)

        For Each i In FindRange
            If i = "RCA Pending" Then
                Msg = Msg & i.Address & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next i

        MsgBox "Found 'RCA Pending' in cell" & " " & Msg, vbExclamation, "Attention"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with Fadi's because it works when I open the workbook which is what needs to trigger this sub. I did give an upvote for yours though as it is a solid answer.

Comment: Okay, just put the code in your auto open subroutine?

Comment: I would do that, but read my comment above about the new requirement change.